# How to CALCULATE correctly in PowerBI using DAX to SUM and then DIVIDE by GROUPBY function

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset that I want to derive a calculated result from in PowerBI, example below of the dataset TABLE.

I need to calculate a Volume per Day from the sum of the 'Value' column divided by the 'Days in Month' column and subsetting for the other variables Country, Town, Date.

The problem I have is that the as each row repeats the days in Month the 'Days in Month' variable in the formula is aggregating and I don't want it to - .  That is, for March I want 31 not 62 etc.  The result below demonstrates the issue (as PowerBI I cannot post code unfortunately):

```
TABLE
    Country      Town       Date              Value       Days in Month
    -------      ----       -----             -----        ----------
    France       Paris      02/01/2022        1,000           28
    France       Paris      02/01/2022        1,800           28
    Italy        Rome       02/01/2022        2,000           28
    Italy        Rome       02/01/2022        3,600           28

    France       Paris      03/01/2022        2,000           31
    France       Paris      03/01/2022        1,100           31
    Italy        Rome       03/01/2022        4,000           31
    Italy        Rome       03/01/2022        2,200           31

    RESULT required:
    ----------------
    02/01/2022   France Volume per day   =  (2,800 / 28) = 100
    02/01/2022   Italy Volume per day    =  (5,600 / 28) = 200
    03/01/2022   France Volume per day   =  (3,100 / 31) = 100
    03/01/2022   Italy Volume per day    =  (6,200 / 31) = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have "Days in Month" column in your dataset, you can use this below measure-

```
result = sum(your_table[Value])/AVERAGE(your_table[Days in Month])
```

or, if you don not have the "Days in Month" column in your dataset, you can create this below measure-

```
result_2 = 

var number_of_day_current_month = DAY(EOMONTH(MIN(your_table_name[Date]),0))

return SUM(your_table_name[Value])/number_of_day_current_month
```

and here is the output of both measures-

[image]